# Odd Simple Search Results

Tags: search, simple-search

I'm having odd results with `exp:search:simple_form` and certain keywords. For instance, a search for *1010* returns results with:

1. XP1010
2. 81010
3. 1010

If I add a hypen to the search, *1010-24*, it returns no results? Why is this?

```
{exp:search:simple_form 
    channel="not product_options|color_charts" 
    form_class="search"
    result_page="search/results"
    search_in="entries"
    show_expired="yes"
    show_future_entries="yes"
    status="not closed"
    where="any"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. I didn't have a matrix field searchable. Updating the settings for that field & column fixed the results. Now, I just need to figure out how to bulk update entries so they get included in the index. Hmmm...

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any entries with 1010-24 in the title? My thought is it's looking specifically for a value of "1010-24" not "1010" "-" "24".

Comment: I would agree with this guess.